# Задать для двух доменов одну директорию

Tags: php, linux, nginx, centos, apache2

Добрый на сервере VDS сайт работает через связку nginx + apache. Появилась задача добавить еще один домен для текущего сайта. Для каждого домена будет свой шаблон. У каждого домена будут поддомены.

Я собирался создать два VirtualHost в apache, указав одинаковый DocumentRoot, но техподдержка сервера сказала, что "это так не работает" и предложила создать VirtualHost для одного домена, а второй домен указать в ServerAlias. Но в этом случае нельзя указать ssl ключи для каждого домена(ssl уже куплены).

Подскажите что делать? В чем проблема указывать одинаковый DocumentRoot для двух доменов?

*Я постараюсь узнать у тех.поддержки в чем проблема указывать одинаковый DocumentRoot для разный виртуальных хостов, но не уверен, что мне ответят*

Comment: Технически в Апаче такое возможно без каких-либо проблем, но вы небось через какую-нибудь панельку это делаете, в которой такое невозможно?

Comment: @de_frag На сервере установлена vesta, на которой можно создавать новые домены(виртуальные хосты). Также есть доступ к SSH

Comment: Тут уж сами решайте как быть: либо забейте на панельку (если действительно через нее нельзя, но очень надо) и настраивайте все что необходимо руками (если через ssh прав хватит на все настройки); либо смиритесь с хостингом и делайте, как саппорт предлагает.

Comment: @de_frag У меня конфиги имеют такой формат названия domain.ru.httpd.conf и domain.ru.nginx.conf, я так понимаю перед тем как запросу попасть к конфигам, он обрабатывается еще чем-то, а затем перенаправляет к нужным конфигам в зависимости от домена.Вы не сталкивались с такой структурой? Перед тем как создать новые конфиги new_domain.ru.httpd.conf и new_domain.ru.nginx.conf мне надо еще где-то инициализировать новый домен?